# How to plot data from Hierarchical columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I have this table, and I want to create a scatter plot of say left Hippocampus in axis "X" against left Cerebral Cortex in axis "Y", because is a hierarchical column I don't know how to choose the specific column I need.

I  tried:

```
tabla1.plot(kind="scatter", x=(tabla1.iloc[:, tabla1.columns.get_level_values(Hippocampus)=='left']), y=(tabla1.iloc[:, tabla1.columns.get_level_values(["Cerebral Cortex "])=='left']), alpha=0.6, c='black')
```

but I got this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Can you help me?

Also, how can I get rid of the hierarchical columns and create separate columns instead?

| RID | str_dx | Cerebral cortex left | Cerebral cortex right | hippotalamus left | hippotalamus right |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

because I think is easier to work in this way.

Thanks.

Following a recomendation from a comment, I give you a code similar to the one I used to create the table.

First, an example dataframe (sorry, I tried to make it similar):

```
data = {'RID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5], 'Str_dx': ['CN', 'CN', 'CN', 'CN', 'MCI', 'MCI', 'MCI', 'MCI', 'MCI;Dementia', 'MCI;Dementia', 'MCI;Dementia', 'MCI;Dementia', 'CN', 'CN', 'CN', 'CN', 'MCI', 'MCI', 'MCI', 'MCI'], 'reg_name': ['Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex', 'Hippocampus', 'Cerebral Cortex'], 'reg_side': ['left', 'left', 'right', 'right', 'left', 'left', 'right', 'right', 'left', 'left', 'right', 'right', 'left', 'left', 'right', 'right', 'left', 'left', 'right', 'right'], 'gm_vol': [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

then, I used the following code to create the final hierarchical table:

```
tab = pd.pivot_table(df, values='gm_vol', index=['RID', 'Str_dx'], columns=['reg_name', 'reg_side'])
tab
```

I hope this help.

Comment: You provided code for plotting the data. However, we need to see the code which creates a table of data similar to yours. The table created for testing purposes should have the same column and row labels, but only a small amount of data (at most 10 rows of data)

Comment: a quick way is to edit the post and copy-paste the output of `table1.head(3).to_dict()` and `table1.tail(3).to_dict()`

Comment: Thanks!, I spent the last 40 mins trying to make something similar :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Flattened table

> Also, how can I get rid of the hierarchical columns and create separate columns instead?

To get rid of the MultiIndex:

```py
tab.columns = [' '.join(column).strip() for column in tab.columns]
tab = tab.reset_index()

#    RID        Str_dx  Cerebral Cortex left  Cerebral Cortex right  Hippocampus left  Hippocampus right
# 0    1            CN                    11                     13                10                 12
# 1    2           MCI                    15                     17                14                 16
# 2    3  MCI;Dementia                    19                     11                18                 10
# 3    4            CN                    13                     15                12                 14
# 4    5           MCI                    17                     19                16                 18
```

Then the plot command is simple:

```py
tab.plot.scatter(x='Cerebral Cortex left', y='Hippocampus left')
```

---

#### Hierarchical table

It sounds like you prefer to flatten the table, but just for completeness, you can use [**`DataFrame.xs()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) to slice the MultiIndex.

If you want left cerebral cortex vs left hippocampus, specify `key='left'` in `level=1` (second level) along `axis=1` (columns). Then plot with `x='Cerebral Cortex', y='Hippocampus'`:

```py
tab.xs(
    key='left',
    level=1,
    axis=1,
).plot.scatter(
    x='Cerebral Cortex',
    y='Hippocampus',
    ylabel='Hippocampus',
    title='Left',
    legend=False,
)
```

[image: 'left' plot]

Similarly if you wanted left vs right cerebral cortex, specify `key='Cerebral Cortex'` in `level=0` (first level) along `axis=1` (columns):

```py
tab.xs(
    key='Cerebral Cortex',
    level=0,
    axis=1,
).plot.scatter(
    x='left',
    y='right',
    ylabel='right',
    title='Cerebral Cortex',
    legend=False,
)
```